# How to calculate the total value of dynamically added row-inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add dynamically row (one row have 3 columns  ) and I want to calculate 2 columns and the sum will display one the left column.when I add multiple row each column calculation will differently show and total sum will display such as

```
4*2=8`
4*3=12
Total=20
```

**HTML code**

```js
// add row
var x = 1;
$('#addButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (x < 10) {
    x++;
    $('#addRow').append('<div class="row"><input type="text" class="com_quantity"><input type="text" class="com_per"><input type="text" class="com_total"></div>');
  } else {
    alert('Only 10 row alloted');
  }
});

// remove row
$('#addRow').on("click", "#remove_field", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  x--;    
});

// calculation section
/*---- Calcucation section--*/
$('.com_quantity').keyup(function() {
  var quantity = $(this).val();
  var com_per = $('.com_per').val();
  commission(quantity, com_per, 0);
});
$('.com_per').keyup(function() {
  var com_per = $(this).val();
  var quantity = $('.com_quantity').val();
  commission(quantity, com_per, 0);
})

function commission(quantity, com_per, total_com) {
  var quantity = quantity;
  var com_per = com_per;
  var total_com = total_com;
  total = quantity * com_per;
}
```

```html
<div class="x_content">
  <div class="" id="addRow">
    <!-- here will add the row-->
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add New">
</div>
```

**My aspect ion result**

when I add row multiplication result will display individually and total sum will display under. if I remove/decrease or add row the result will change. Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 0):

from the info that you provided, and what i could understand, this is what i come up with.

hopefully it's what you need.

```js
// add row
   var x = 1;

   $('#addButton').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if(x < 10) {

     x++; 

     $('#addRow').append('<div class="row"><input type="text" class="com_quantity"><input type="text" class="com_per"><input type="text" class="com_total"></div>');
    }
    else{

     alert('Only 10 row alloted');
    } 

   });

   // remove row
   $('#addRow').on("click","#remove_field", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
    x--;
        
        // when a row is removed recalculate sum of total commissions
    sumTotalCommissions();

   });

   $('#addRow').on('input', '.com_quantity', function() {

    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var com_per = $(this).siblings('.com_per').val() || 0;

    var commission = quantity * com_per;

    if (commission) {

     $(this).siblings('.com_total').val(commission);
          
          sumTotalCommissions();
    }

   });

   $('#addRow').on('input', '.com_per', function() {

    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var com_per = $(this).siblings('.com_quantity').val() || 0;

    var commission = quantity * com_per;

    if (commission) {

     $(this).siblings('.com_total').val(commission);
          
          sumTotalCommissions();
    }
   });
      
      
      var sumTotalCommissions = function() {

    var total_commissions = 0;

    $('#addRow .com_total').each(function(index, com_total) {

     total_commissions += parseInt($(com_total).val());
    });

    $('#totalCommissions').html(total_commissions);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  
  <div class="x_content">
   <div class="" id="addRow">
    <!-- here will add the row-->
   </div>
      
      <div style="margin-left: 350px;">
    Total commissions : <span id="totalCommissions"></span>
   </div>
      
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add New">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i want to know how can i  sum total commission

Comment: @Md.AzharulIslam do you have another column for the sum of total commisions?

Comment: i want sum of commission will show bottom of total row it will depend on row increase or decrease. as like **28**

Comment: @Md.AzharulIslam i updated my answer, run the snippet to see the updates.

Comment: if i use bootstrap grid system such as "col-sm-4" into the "row" then "siblings()" function will not work and what can i do.i have changed my HTML code @chebaby

Comment: @Md.AzharulIslam please provide us with the your full HTML markup.